# Removing folder structure when making a tar from a folder

Tags: php, exec, tar

Ok I don't really want to waste any more time on investigating this but I do want to offer a .tar option for download instead of just zip.

```
    $archive = "/home/stevenbu/public_html/temp/".$twitter_name.".tar";
    $directory = "/home/stevenbu/public_html/temp/".$twitter_name;
    exec("tar -cf $archive $directory");
```

The problem is that when I extract the .tar it is 5 folders deep I would like no folders and just the files in the .tar

Many thanks

Comment: Not really a PHP question, more of a tar question.

Comment: and tar doesn't have a 'junk folders' option...

Comment: While not directly related to your question, **always** consider the possibility that someone enters *`$(rm -rf ~)`* as their Twitter name.

Comment: @AJ
It is PHP related as it's run from php exec and not directly. Which does make a difference in certain situations.

@grawity
Thanks for the heads up, but Twitter would not let you have that name and users must authenticate with twitter to use the script. The twitter name comes from me not from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I last used php, but

```
exec("cd /home/stevenbu/public_html/temp/;tar -cf $archive $directory");
```

would help in shell.

Comment: This does work but instead I needed to use && instead of ; otherwise it went back to the default directory.

    exec("cd /home/stevenbu/public_html/temp/;tar -cf $archive $directory");

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent = "/home/stevenbu/public_html/temp";
$dir = $twitter_name;
$archive = $twitter_name.".tgz";

exec('tar -cz -f '.escapeshellarg($archive).' -C '.escapeshellarg($parent).' '.escapeshellarg($dir));
```

This one is slightly better, because it outputs the `.tar.gz` file directly to the browser, instead of creating a temporary file:

```
$parent = "/home/stevenbu/public_html/temp";
$dir = $twitter_name;
$archive = $twitter_name.".tar.gz";

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.addslashes($archive).'"');
passthru('tar -cz -C '.escapeshellarg($parent).' '.escapeshellarg($dir));
```